# Preciso conectar a um servidor FTP SSH em PHP

Tags: php, ftp, ssh

Tenho esse codigo:

```
<?php
$ftp_server="MEUHOST.COM";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, 2222) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 
if (!ftp_connect($ftp_server))
echo "not connected";
else
echo "successful connected";
?>
```

mas ele não está conectando em ssh.

Comment: http://php.net/ftp_ssl_connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro você tem que ter certeza do que quer acessar SSH ou SFTP, são coisas relativamente diferentes, não funciona com `ftp_connect`.

Não existem métodos nativos para SSH ou SFTP em PHP, mas existem libs de terceiros em repositórios ou via composer e via PECL, no caso do PECL existe o pacote [SSH2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ssh2.php#ref.ssh2) (requer PECL 0.9), você pode baixar manualmente e compilar e se for *Windows Server* pode baixar a `.dll` que for compatível com sua versão do PHP em https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2.

Se for usar o SSH2 para se conectar com SSH use o método [`ssh2_connect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php), se for usar SFTP então junto ao ao `ssh2_connect` use o [`ssh2_sftp`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php)

### Exemplo de conexão SSH usando SSH2

```
<?php
function ssh_desconectado($reason, $message, $language) {
    printf("O servidor foi desconectado, código [%d] e mensagem: %s\n", $reason, $message);
}

// Ajuste aqui com os dados para conexão
$methods = array(
    'kex' => 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1',
    'client_to_server' => array(
        'crypt' => '3des-cbc',
        'comp' => 'none'
    ),
    'server_to_client' => array(
        'crypt' => 'aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc',
        'comp' => 'none'
    )
);

$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22, $methods, array(
    'disconnect' => 'ssh_desconectado')
);

if (!$connection) die('conexão falhou');
```

### Exemplo de conexão com SFTP usando SSH2

> Talvez tenha que passar o `$methods` como no exemplo anterior

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
```

E as funções que deve usar para gerenciar o SFTP são:

- [`ssh2_sftp_chmod`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ssh2-sftp-chmod.php) — muda as permissões de um arquivo
- [`ssh2_sftp_mkdir`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ssh2-sftp-mkdir.php) — Cria uma pasta
- [`ssh2_sftp_readlink`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ssh2-sftp-readlink.php) — Retorna o algo de um link simbólico
- [`ssh2_sftp_realpath`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ssh2-sftp-realpath.php) — Pega o caminho absoluto/real de um caminho fornecido na string
- [`ssh2_sftp_rename`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ssh2-sftp-rename.php) — Renomeia um arquivo
- [`ssh2_sftp_rmdir`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ssh2-sftp-rmdir.php) — Remove uma pasta
- [`ssh2_sftp_symlink`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ssh2-sftp-symlink.php) — Cria um link simbólico
- [`ssh2_sftp_unlink`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ssh2-sftp-unlink.php) — Deleta um arquivo

---

### Alternativas ao SSH2

Se não tiver como compilar uma extensão em seu servidor você pode escrever manualmente as instruções usando `fsockopen` ou `stream_socket_client` para iniciar uma conexão e `fwrite` para escrever as instruções SSH e/ou SFTP.

Também existem repositórios (muitos deles com suporte a composer) que fornecem suporte a SSH sem depender de compilações: https://github.com/search?l=PHP&q=sftp&ype=Repositories

Answer (score 1):

Bom, acredito que esteja utilizando o SFTP:

> SFTP, que significa SSH File Transfer Protocol, ou Secure File Transfer Protocol, é um protocolo separado, empacotado com SSH que funciona de forma similar em cima de uma conexão segura.

Para utilizar este recurso no PHP, você precisa do [ssh2_sftp](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ssh2-sftp.php).

De acordo com o manual do PHP:

```
<?php

$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

$stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/path/to/file", 'r');
?>
```

Um exemplo completo utilizando como classe, que também está na página do manual do PHP:

```
<?php

class SFTPConnection
{
    private $connection;
    private $sftp;

    public function __construct($host, $port=22)
    {
        $this->connection = @ssh2_connect($host, $port);
        if (! $this->connection)
            throw new Exception("Could not connect to $host on port $port.");
    }

    public function login($username, $password)
    {
        if (! @ssh2_auth_password($this->connection, $username, $password))
            throw new Exception("Could not authenticate with username $username " .
                                "and password $password.");

        $this->sftp = @ssh2_sftp($this->connection);
        if (! $this->sftp)
            throw new Exception("Could not initialize SFTP subsystem.");
    }

    public function uploadFile($local_file, $remote_file)
    {
        $sftp = $this->sftp;
        $stream = @fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp$remote_file", 'w');

        if (! $stream)
            throw new Exception("Could not open file: $remote_file");

        $data_to_send = @file_get_contents($local_file);
        if ($data_to_send === false)
            throw new Exception("Could not open local file: $local_file.");

        if (@fwrite($stream, $data_to_send) === false)
            throw new Exception("Could not send data from file: $local_file.");

        @fclose($stream);
    }
}

?>
```

Utilização da classe acima:

```
try
{
    $sftp = new SFTPConnection("localhost", 22);
    $sftp->login("username", "password");
    $sftp->uploadFile("/tmp/to_be_sent", "/tmp/to_be_received");
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```